# CSS эффект для текста

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такой эффект в CSS, и если можете, подскажите как такой эффект называется, я даже не до конца понимаю "как его гуглить"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080671/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, пример ниже.

Ищите по `CSS text gradient`, чтобы разнообразить пример и настроить под нужный градиент и/или цвет.

```css
span {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #CDCCCC 0%, #000000 50%, #CDCCCC 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS эффект для текста</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <span>CSS эффект для текста</span>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ТС, примите ответ)